# Adding gmail contacts in ichat for me.com account

Tags: macos, ichat

I have a @me.com account and I created an Ichat account using it. I am trying to add my gmail contacts from the address book/ adding just the gmail addresses. Noone seems to get my invitations. Why so? Is @me.com account only for adding @me.com accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a me.com account in iChat, this will serve as an AIM account. If you want to add your Google Talk/Google+ friends with Gmail addresses, then you will have to add a Google account in iChat. This is very simple to do in Lion, simply go to iChat>Preferences, click on Accounts, and hit the small + button in the bottom left. Then you will be prompted to add new account information and just select the option from the popup box called Google Talk. Then all you need to do is enter your Google account information and you will now have all your Google friends in iChat.

Comment: Oh actually thats what I didn't want, I wanted to add only few and not all gmail friends. That was the purpose of the new account.

Comment: You can remove any of the people you have on the list. But to answer the question then, no you can't use me.com with Google Talk.